# How to create ASP.NET MVC 6 project in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise version

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc

I have Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition. Can I create an ASP.NET MVC 6 project?

Step 1: Create a new project.

[image]

Step 2: Select "ASP.NET Web Application(.NET Framework)"

[image]

You can see I don't have ASP.NET 5 Template

Answer (score 1):

MVC6 has been renamed to ASP.NET Core 1.0 long back.

To Create, ASP.NET Core MVC application, you can use **ASP.NET Core Web Application** template from your first screenshot.

There are 2 templates for ASP.NET Core Web Application. For choosing the right .NET for you, refer this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server).

Also see [ASP.NET 5 is dead - Introducing ASP.NET Core 1.0 and .NET Core 1.0](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for you help. But in this time i get reference error.https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQjkv.png My Reference Nuget Package source is https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGzIU.png

Comment: You need to install .NET core SDK and runtime from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core). Please refer official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/) too.